# How to compare two huge file csv efficiently with lesser time

Tags: python, linux, csv

I need to compare two large csv files.
But the thing is I have to iterate each line of `file1` with all other lines of `file2` and do some computation for different columns.

Part of my code that I tried in python:

```
import csv

def getOverlap(a,b):
    return max(0, min(a[1], b[1]) - max(a[0], b[0]))


masterlist = [row for row in c2]

for hosts_row in c1:
    chr1 = hosts_row[3]
    a1 = [int(hosts_row[4]),int(hosts_row[5])]
    found = False
    for master_row in masterlist:
        if hosts_row[7] == master_row[7]:
            c3.writerow(hosts_row)

            chr2 = master_row[3]

            b1 = [int(master_row[4]),int(master_row[5])]
            if getOverlap(a1,b1) != 0 and chr1 == chr2:
                c5.writerow(hosts_row)
            else:
                c6.writerow(hosts_row)


            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        c4.writerow(hosts_row)
        found2 = False
        for master_row2 in masterlist:
            chr2 = master_row[3]
            b1 = [int(master_row[4]),int(master_row[5])]
            if getOverlap(a1,b1) != 0 and chr1 == chr2:
                c7.writerow(hosts_row)
                found2 = True
                break
        if not found2:
            c8.writerow(hosts_row)
```

But it takes about 5 to 6 hours of running. Is there any quicker way for it. I have 16gb ram.

Comment: It may or may not help to know the sizes of the files.

Comment: why not load them in DB and run SQL query ?

Answer (score 2):

The point is not how big are your files, it's a question of your goal and algorithm design.

- one point is to define what are `differences`.
- If the rows are ordered in the same way on both files, then two different rows would be    having different columns.

So, maybe you should first consider sorting the csv files so the row order is identical, and then you can simply use the module [filecpmp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html).

I realize this answer is not really adding any code, but it offers some thinking materail. It just to long for a single comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use Meld application in linux(ubuntu) to compare to files line by line

Comment: This will overflow the memory of the computer if the files are VERY large. If each is about 6 GB and the Computer has only 8GB RAM (like an average laptop today)... you can see what is going to happen. So this answer is quite problematic.